# Export ChainMap Data Output to CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

Below is a chainmap/beautifulsoup scraper that scrapes a physician's profile information from this [website](https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page=%25s).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from collections import ChainMap


def get_data(soup):
    default_data = {'name': 'n/a', 'clinic': 'n/a', 'profession': 'n/a', 'region': 'n/a', 'city': 'n/a'}

    for doctor in soup.select('.view-practitioners .practitioner'):
        doctor_data = {}

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text.strip():
            doctor_data['name'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text.strip():
            doctor_data['clinic'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text.strip():
            doctor_data['profession'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text.strip():
            doctor_data['region'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text.strip():
            doctor_data['city'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text

        yield ChainMap(doctor_data, default_data)


url = 'https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page=%s'

for i in range(5):
    page=requests.get(url % i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

def print_data(header_text, data, key):
    print(header_text)
    for d in data:
        print(d[key])
    print()

data = list(get_data(soup))
print_data('[Names]', data, 'name')
print_data('[Clinic]', data, 'clinic')
print_data('[Profession]', data, 'profession')
print_data('[Taxonomy]', data, 'region')
print_data('[City]', data, 'city')


f=csv.writer('Sports_Medicine_List','w')
f.writerow(['Names','Clinic', 'Profession','Taxonomy','City'])
for i in range(len('Names')):
    f.writerow(['Names'[i],'Clinic'[i], 'Profession'[i],'Taxonomy'[i],'City'[i]])
```

The code runs with no errors, however, a csv output is not showing up in my IDE. I think it is because I am not accounting for the chainmap variables correctly but I am not entirely sure. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing csv dictionary you can use `csv.DictWriter` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), `ChainMap` is just a version of dictionary):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
from collections import ChainMap

def get_data(soup):
    default_data = {'name': 'n/a', 'clinic': 'n/a', 'profession': 'n/a', 'region': 'n/a', 'city': 'n/a'}

    for doctor in soup.select('.view-practitioners .practitioner'):
        doctor_data = {}

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text.strip():
            doctor_data['name'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text.strip():
            doctor_data['clinic'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text.strip():
            doctor_data['profession'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text.strip():
            doctor_data['region'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text

        if doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text.strip():
            doctor_data['city'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text

        yield ChainMap(doctor_data, default_data)


url = 'https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page=%s'

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ['name', 'clinic', 'profession', 'region', 'city']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in range(5):
        page=requests.get(url % i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        writer.writerows(get_data(soup)
```

)

This outputs all data to `data.csv` file. Screenshot from my LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks again Andrej! I really appreciate all the help with this project. I have learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 1):

This is another way you might consider giving a try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_data(link):
    for pagelink in [link.format(page) for page in range(5)]:
        res = requests.get(pagelink)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

        data = []
        for doctor in soup.select('.view-practitioners .practitioner'):
            doctor_data = {}

            doctor_data['name'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__name').text
            doctor_data['clinic'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__clinic').text
            doctor_data['profession'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__profession').text
            doctor_data['region'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__region').text
            doctor_data['city'] = doctor.select_one('.practitioner__city').text
            data.append(doctor_data)

        for item in data:
            writer.writerow(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://sportmedbc.com/practitioners?field_profile_first_name_value=&field_profile_last_name_value=&field_pract_profession_tid=All&city=&taxonomy_vocabulary_5_tid=All&page={}'
    with open("doctorsinfo.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
        fieldnames = ['name', 'clinic', 'profession', 'region', 'city']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(infile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        get_data(url)
```